# Bevel vertices on a flat plane

Tags: modeling, bevel

I imagine there’s an easy fix but at the moment I just don’t have any idea how to do that.

[image]

I made a flat plane, made some loopcuts to divide it and now want the corners to be round. It works for the corners which are "outside" but for the corners which lie "inside" the form it does not work. My aim is that the bevel looks like the red marked curve in my example.

How can I solve that?

Edit:
To make it more clear: when I try to bevel the "inside" vertex I get something like that, but not a curve.

[image]

Comment: I deleted my answer which wasn't correct. You can bevel single vertices by pressing V while in bevel mode ; it works well with "outside" corners, but with "inside" corners it don't allow to curve the profile, just do a straight bevel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's dependent on the internal edges.

- Starting as shown
- <kbd>X</kbd> > Limited Dissolve (selected) internal edges
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> Bevel (selected) corner vertices

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks…though the loopcuts are gone now.

Comment: @faybn I suppose you could extrude the boundary edges up, then bevel the newly-formed vertical edges, then delete the new  top vertices ..

Answer (score -1):

It's pretty hard to get a shape like that. But with a little work around you can do something like this:
[image: Final_Result]
First, I just created something like you did. Just a plane with some extrusions:
[image: 1]
Next I just beveled the outer edges with `ctrl` `shift` `b`
[image: 2]
Select the respective vertices and duplicate them. Move them to the required location.
[image: 3]
[image: 4]
rotate them on the z axis 180 degrees
[image: 5]
move them to the required location[image: 6]
subdivide the connecting edges
[image: 7]
[image: 8]
Now merge the end vertices of the duplicate with the subdivided vertices
[image: 9]
[image: 10]
now select these vertices and fill them with `f`
[image: 11]
Getting out of object mode will now provide you with this:
[image: 12]
There is probably another way but at the moment this is the one I came up with. Took a lot of time to do all the images. Thanks for asking.